# Como usar HATBM com vários models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-tags

Vou ter o model `Tag` ele vai ter relacionamento `HABTM`com `POSTS`.

Porém, quero que ele tenha também relacionamento `HABTM` com `USERS` pois meu objetivo é no futuro conseguir encontrar posts que tenham as mesmas tags que o user.

Como faço? Crio um relacionamento comum, criando duas tabelas separadas para tanto?
E depois, como faço pra pesquisar os posts que tenham as mesmas tags que determinado user?

Answer (score 1):

Sim, você terâ que criar relacionamentos separados. No total você terá 5 tabelas:

```
users
tags_users
tags
posts_tags
posts
```

Depois se você quiser consultar, por exemplo, todos os posts que compartilhem tags com um determinado usuário, faça:

```
user = Users.first
posts.joins(tags: :users).where(tags: {user: user})
```

Ou se essa sintaxe nao funcionar tente

```
posts.joins(tags: :users).where('users.id' => user)
```

PS: existem maneiras mais eficientes de fazer essa query mas nao vou focar nisso.

Comment: Mais um comentário. É possível usar a opção :through no has_and_belongs_to_many. Eu nunca tentei, mas depois que você estiver com as 5 tabelas e os relacionamentos funcionando você pode tentar adicionar essa opção.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, surgiro o uso da associação `has_many model, :through table`

Segue descrição da documentação:

> The has_many :through Association
>   A has_many :through association is often used to set up a many-to-many connection with another model. This association indicates that the declaring model can be matched with zero or more instances of another model by proceeding through a third model. For example, consider a medical practice where patients make appointments to see physicians. The relevant association declarations could look like this:
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Em alguns projetos utilizei a gem `acts-as-taggable-on` que é muito boa para trabalhar com taggs, segue o [link](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on). Espero ter ajudado,